# Fetching data for filtering using named query Filtering data

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a field in database called marks(Number(2,2)) in Oracle db
I am using Java and Spring JPA repository.

Marks field contains data of 0,0.5,0.05,0.50,.35,.31,1.45,4,4.60 etc...

Now in UI I have a filtering field which is used to filter data.
If my input is 0 it should return all the numbers containing 0 in it i.e. 0,0.5,0.05,0.50,4.60 
When am using to_char() it is converting 0.5 to .5 and  0.50 to .5 
so am not getting the proper result

What should be the way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Why use to_char?

I would leave as number and do something along the lines of

where ***yourfield*** between ***yourInput*** and (***yourInput*** + 1)

This means if your input is 0 then it will be any value between 0 and 1, if your input is 1 then it will be all values between 1 and 2 ect

I am making the assumption that you have only whole numbers in your UI field, and the same rule applies for all inputs.